# Starting ACTION_DIAL Intent from OnClickListener - android - Java

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` which displays user information and a call button. Now I want to create a dial action, so I used this code in my `getView` method:

```
   Button callB = (Button)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.bCall);
        callB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + user.getPhoneNumber())));
                        }
        });
```

However, the method `startActivity` is not available within the `OnClickListener`. How can I solve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this piece of code is in your ArrayAdapter, and the getView() method is for getting the view of each list item. If that is the case then, you can store each user's phone number in a hashmap, mapping the button's pointer id to the number, and then have the array adapter itself implement View.OnClickListener to receive click events for views:

```
public class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{
    HashMap<int, String> mMap;

    public myAdapter(){
        mMap = new HashMap<int, String>;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup container){
        // initialize view . . .
        . . .

        Button callB = (Button)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.bCall);
        callB.setOnClickListener(this);
        mMap.put(callB.getId(), "phone-number-goes-here");

        . . .
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if (mMap.containsKey(v.getId())){
            getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + mMap.get(v.getId())));
        }

    }

}
```